# Inertial mass, and energy required to accelerate from 100 kph to 101 kph versus 1000 kph to 1001 kph

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light, acceleration

In [this article](https://futurism.com/why-do-objects-increase-in-mass-as-they-get-faster-2) it says "It is commonly known that, if you accelerate an object, its mass will increase; however, to understand why this phenomenon occurs, we mustn’t think of the object’s mass increasing. Instead, we should think of its energy... when we speak of an objects mass increasing due to acceleration, we are really talking about its inertial mass increasing."

I understand that. But let's say I'm pushing a rock East at 100kph.  I understand that if I suddenly wanted to push it West, I would be pushing the weight plus the momentum of the rock (the total of these would be the inertial mass).  But if I only want to accelerate the object in the East direction, Does it take more energy for me to accelerate it from 1000kph to 1001kph than it took for me to accelerate it from 100kph to 101kph?

I have looked at all the links from questions like this, but I can't find that particular answer.

Comment: Futurism.com is a bad place to learn physics.

Comment: *Does it take more energy for me to accelerate it from 1000kph to 1001kph than it took for me to accelerate it from 100kph to 101kph?* Yes, even in non-relativistic mechanics. Try calculating the kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ at each of those four speeds. Relativistically, the energy increases *even faster*.

Comment: Mass doesn't get bigger, 4-velocity's time and space comments get bigger: $p_{\mu} = mu_{\mu}$, after all.

Comment: @JEB I don’t think the OP has learned about four-vectors, given the confusion about how Newtonian KE increases with speed.

Comment: Your example seems to not really deal with special relativity. Perhaps you are mixing things up here?

Comment: @G.Smith  You are describing the kinetic energy of the rock.  Yes it certainly has more energy at 1000kph than it did at 100kph and it would be much harder to reverse the direction of travel.  But why is it more difficult to push it 1kph faster East.

Comment: @AaronStevens   I'm trying to understand why it is more difficult to accelerate from c-2 to c-1.  So I'll get there eventually.

Comment: Calculate the *change* in the kinetic energy between 100 and 101 kph, then calculate the change between 1000 and 1001 kph. If you are still confused about why it is more difficult after doing this calculation for, say, a 1 kg rock, explain what confuses you.

Comment: @G.Smith  I see the kinetic energy numbers (for a 1kg rock) are 5000 to 5100.5 and 500000 to 501000.5   So yes the jump in energy is much larger according to the formula.  But that still doesn't explain WHY it takes more energy to accelerate the rock 1kph faster when at higher speed.

Comment: You didn’t ask why KE has the formula it has. You asked why it gets harder to accelerate something. It gets harder because you have to come up with more energy for each increment in speed.

Comment: In any case, none of this has anything to do with relativity.

Comment: @G.Smith  It's all time dilation and gravity.  I'll ponder these for a while.

Comment: This has nothing to do with either time dilation or gravity. You need to ponder the work-energy theorem of Newtonian mechanics and understand why kinetic energy increases as the square of the speed.

Comment: This question and uncertainty is a *prime* example of why the concept of relativistic mass should be abandoned.  Relativistic mass is different for forces applied in different directions.  BTW, I read the article you linked.  I agree with the first comment.  I wouldn't read anything from that website from now on.

Comment: In modern formulations of relativity, the mass of an object *does not change* with speed. Whoever wrote the terrible Futurism article isn’t up-to-date.

Comment: @G.Smith  But they do say that it is "inertial mass" that increases.  So the rock doesn't get any heavier.  It just gets more energy.  And under e=mc^2 mass and energy are interchangeable.  Is this a correct interpretation of what the article says?

Comment: I’m not going to comment further on that misleading article, other than to say that mass and energy are not “interchangeable”. They are very different things. For example, a photon always has energy but never has mass. Comments are not for long discussions, so I’m done.

Comment: The point of my comment was to show the effect is entirely geometrical, and $m=m$ as long as the Higgs field is 'on'.  If that article makes you think internal and gravitational mass differ, then abandon it even faster. There is simply nothing to be gained, and much to be lost, from "relativistic mass".

Comment: I suggest you re-ask this as one question, not 2 vastly different ones. Moreover, be specific about the concept or point that is confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

The relativistic increase in mass is calculated from the instantaneous speed of the object.  Different observers, who may be travelling at different speeds themselves, will see different relativistic masses for your object.  The relativistic change in mass is not a property of the object, it belongs to the individual observer and depends on the object's velocity as seen by that observer.

But the question you ask can be answered without any consideration of relativity.  It takes in rough terms 10 times more energy to increase an object's speed from 1000 kph to 1001kph as it does to increase its speed from 100 to 101kph irrespective of relativistic effects.

That is because kinetic energy is proportional to the speed squared, nothing to do with Einstein's theory of Special Relativity.

Comment: "Different observers, who may be traveling at different speeds themselves, will see different relativistic masses for your object."  If I'm on a train traveling at 1000kph and I accelerate the rock from 0-1kph it only increases energy by 0.5 from my position.  But to an outside observer, it increases energy by 1000.5   from his position.  Seems like it has lots to do with relativity.   I think I just asked my original question incorrectly.  Thanks.

Comment: You're right of course.  Relativity doesn't have to mean Einstein's Special Relativity.